# converting a matrix of NAs to 0s and continous variables to 1s in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix populated with NAs and continuous values. I need to convert NAs to 0s and continuous values to 1s. How can I do this in R?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `m` is as in the Note at the end:

```
1 - is.na(m)
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    0    1
## [2,]    1    0
```

### Note

```
m <- matrix(c(NA, 2, 3, NA), 2)
m
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]   NA    3
## [2,]    2   NA
```

Comment: OR `+(!is.na(m))`

Comment: That would work although note that it is the same number of non-space characters and the given answer uses only one operation in addition to is.na whereas that one uses two.

Comment: Of course it all has to be done in the end but the point is that the answer only specifies one operation rather than two.  It is what is specified, not what is done underneath.

Comment: with `m <- structure(sample(c(1,NA),100000000, replace=TRUE),dim=c(10000,10000))` @d.b 's version is a bit faster, interestingly even consistently faster than `as.numeric(!is.na(m))`

Answer (score 1):

Use the ifelse function:

```
your_matrix <- matrix(c(NA,NA,NA,3.5,2.5,5.0), nrow=2)
your_matrix <- ifelse(is.na(your_matrix), 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have some values in a vector (d) and you have a matrix  (m), then converting the numeric values to 1's and the NA values to 0's can be done with two lines of code.

```
d <- c(NA, NA, 2, 5, NA, 6, NA, 1,  6)
m <- matrix(data = d, nrow = 3, ncol = 3 )


m[is.na(d)] <- 0
m[d > 0 ] <- 1
m


#A matrix:
3 × 3 of 
type dbl
0 1 0
0 0 1
1 1 1
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Try it with `d <- c(NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0,  0)`. Or with some negative values (that are also continuous).